# How do I use KeyDown Events when the form isn't active?

Tags: vb6

When I press Q, I have code that makes my mouse move away and click, therefore making the form inactive, and clicking whatever was there.

Now, when I press Q again, it doesn't work, because the form is inactive. How do I make the KeyDown events still fire when the form is not active?

Comment: Assuming "Visual Basic" you mean VB.Net (not VB6). Please consider showing some related code... And comment on if "not active" means form or whole application.

Comment: Sorry, but please don't change the tags unless you know what I mean. I meant VB6.

Comment: OK changed to VB6 - it was very hard to reason that you meant VB6 since you mention only versions of VS that did not have support for VB6 in the tags - VS 2008/2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your application doesn't have focus then it can not trigger the `KeyDown` events.

In those cases you have two options. Assuming you only want to monitor 1-2 keys then you can register a hotkey using the [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function as seen in this [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/c1a24688-d844-4adc-9d85-416a7158c6ba/).

If you want to monitor more than that then it would be more sensible to use a low level keyboard hook instead.

Comment: This is the correct answer. In Windows, only the focused/active window will receive keyboard events. Everyone else loses, unless they use one of the alternative approaches detailed here. This makes sense: those keyboard events aren't *meant* for other windows, they're only relevant to the window with the focus. That's what focus means. And I strongly recommend against using a low-level keyboard hook. There is little "sensible" about it.

Comment: Although I do agree with the low level keyboard hooks, personally I would take that route instead of using RegisterHotKey to register 10 (or any other number more than a couple) keys. Not to mention sometimes it is not even possible if you have other applications that have already registered that key or if it's reserved by the system. So it depends on the occasion.